# Picture not uploading to database but saving in folder

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

```
public function array_from_post($fields) {
            $data = array();
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
                $data['category_id'] = $this->input->post('category');
```

```html
public function save($data, $id = NULL) {

            // Set timestamps
            if ($this->_timestamps == TRUE) {
                $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $id || $data['created'] = $now;
                $data['modified'] = $now;
            }

            // Insert
            if ($id === NULL) {
                !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
                $this->db->set($data);
                $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
                $id = $this->db->insert_id();
            }

            // Update
            else {
                $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
                $id = $filter($id);
                $this->db->set($data);
                $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
                $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
            }
            return $id;
        }
```

On save this code returns column picture cannot be null. When i do the direct method without using the method array_from_post(), data is saved in the database but i can not save a post to be published at a future date.

Comment: Instead of using the array_from_post method, pass the values direct to the model. I think $this->input->post('picture') is empty.

Comment: when i do that i don't have the option of using different pubdates or even edit the post and change the pubdate.